# Awk to print a column value when column number is not fixed

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file and fields are comma separated but column position is not fixed. Like below:

```
Source Process,Child Process,Script,File Path,File SHA1
explorer.exe,a.exe,None,C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\1.exe,823cb4620650c2373f5b90cabbe7faec1bbdf201
```

It could be like:

```
File Path,File SHA1,Source Process,Child Process,Script
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\1.exe,823cb4620650c2373f5b90cabbe7faec1bbdf201,explorer.exe,a.exe,None
```

I would like to print only file path value and sha1 value if both fields value exist, So I write below for first one:

```
awk -F"," '{if ($4 && $5) print $4,$5}' file.csv | sort | uniq
```

Kindly help me how to get the field number of file path and sha1 and then feed in above code to print both fields. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general solution, using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) f[$i]=i }
    { path=$(f["File Path"]); sha=$(f["File SHA1"]) }
    path && sha { print path, sha }
' file.csv
File Path,File SHA1
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\1.exe,823cb4620650c2373f5b90cabbe7faec1bbdf201
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information on processing CSVs with awk.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an off-by-one error.

In the first example, you say headers are:

```
Source Process,Child Process,Script,File Path, File SHA1
```

but that would make `$5` be  `File SHA1` and `$6` does not exist.

---

To refer to fields by name, you can do:

```
awk -F, '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            k[$i] = i
        fp = k["File Path"]
        fs = k[" File SHA1"]
        if (!fp || !fs) {
            # handle case where column is absent
        }
        next
    }
    $fp && $fs { print $fp,$fs }
' file.csv | sort -u
```

Comment: assumes simple csv where no column contains any quoted commas

Comment: I tried but looks like It did not do anything. I am trying to run on terminal on macOSX. Its appending [ before file name ```Desktop % awk -F"," '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            k[$i] = i
        fp = k["File Path"]
        fs = k["File SHA1"]
        if (!fp || !fs) {
            # handle case where column is absent
        }
        next
    }
    $fp && $fs { print $fp,$fs }
[' file.csv | sort -u
Desktop % ```

Comment: @ghostrider The **it** in the statement "Its appending [" is you :-). Compare the code in your comment to the code in the answer.  The awk code fro m the answer will behave the same way using any awk, mac or otherwise.

Comment: after I wrote my answer, the question has been changed. so my first comment no longer applies. Also the field name I check above is `k[" File SHA1"]` (note the leading space, which has been removed from the question)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to refer to column by its' header rather than position you might create array using [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) string function from header and create another array for each row following way, let say you have `file.csv` as follows

```
Z,Y,X
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

and wants to output columns `Z` and `X` then you might do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR==1{split($0,name);next}{delete row;for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){row[name[i]]=$i};print row["Z"],row["X"]}' file.csv
```

which gives output

```
1 3
4 6
7 9
```

Explanation: for 1st row I populate array `name` which will hold column number-column name pairs and instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line, for all other lines I clear array `row` and then populate it using `for` loop with column name-column value pairs, then I just `print` values for selected columns.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

> `{if ($4 && $5) print $4,$5}`

More common way of expressing that would be using pattern-action rather than lone action with `if` inside, i.e. `($4 && $5){print $4,$5}`

> `| sort | uniq`

You do not need that for limiting output to unique values if you are using GNU `AWK`. If you were tasked with outputting unique pairs of values of 4th and 5th column if both are truth-y you might do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}($4 && $5 && !arr[$4 OFS $5]++){print $4,$5}' file.csv
```

keep in mind that this might result in different order of lines than using sortuniq.